# Looking for something like RailsAdmin, but lighter-weight and not in the same process as the main app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

We've been using rails_admin for a project for a year. It's good, but it would be preferable to have an admin interface that ran in a totally separate process from the main Rails app and from a completely independent code base. rails_admin has so many dependencies that upgrading it along with the main Rails app has proven brittle.

So the functionality we would need is just basic crud for the database tables, with a little bit of magic to make editing associations easier.

Are there any light-weight solutions out there for this? Bonus points for being lightweight & Sinatra-based rather than Rails-based.

Comment: How would this gem (or else) would know about your models, validations etc?

Comment: Maybe I could symlink the app/models directory

Comment: In a related question, I try to solve the issue of sharing models etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133645/how-to-keep-dry-with-a-activeadmin-or-railsadmin-separate-from-the-main-applica/18136464?noredirect=1#18136464

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [git submodules](http://missingreadme.wordpress.com/2010/11/06/how-to-update-submodules-in-git/) or [subversion externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals).  The way I've done something similar to this is to

1. List item migrate the models into a standalone ruby project.
2. put them in a 'core' subdirectory/module.
3. Create a new rails project just for administration.
4. Share the models between the 2 rails apps using an svn external of the 'core' directory into each project's app/models directory.